# Create a subdirectory/subfolder

Tags: powershell, subdirectory

I'm creating a PowerShell script to "compile" a bunch of documentation spread across my notes.  I'd like to create the directory structure first, then copy files into the newly created directories.  I know how to do this manually, but I'm not sure how to approach it in PowerShell.  I'm new to scripting in general, though I do understand programming in several different languages.

Should I change the current directory, then just make some more directories?  Or is there a different approach?

This is what I have so far:

```
#Variables
$containerFolder = "F:\FSG\Packet.Fusion for IT and AV Professionals"
$rootFolder = "Fusion for IT and AV pros $(Get-Date -format “MM-dd-yyyy”)"


#create the directory structure
md -Path $containerFolder -Name $rootFolder
```

I'd like to make several directories within $rootFolder, and 1 or 2 of them will have their own subdirectories.  If I were doing this at the command line, I would cd to the new directory and then md some more.  Is that how to do it with scripting?

**EDIT** This is what I wound up starting with:

```
# Compiles the Fusion packet for distribution

###############################
###########Variables###########
###############################

#folder structure
$FSG = "F:\FSG"
$containerFolder = "Packet.Fusion for IT and AV Professionals"
$rootFolder      = "Fusion for IT and AV pros $(Get-Date -format “MM-dd-yyyy”)"
$subRoot1        = "Fusion Server"
$subRoot2        = "Scheduling Enhancement and Panels"
$subRoot2sub1    = "Scheduling Panels"
$subRoot3        = "SQL Server"

#source folders
$HW      = "0.Hardware"
$3SMDoc  = "0.Hardware\TPMC-3SM.Documentation"
$4SMDoc  = "0.Hardware\TPMC-4SM.Documentation"
$4SMDDoc = "0.Hardware\TPMC-4SM-FD.Documentation"
$730Doc  = "0.Hardware\TSW-730.Documentation"
$730OLH  = "0.Hardware\TSW-730.OLH"
$CENRVS  = "0.Hardware\CEN-RVS.Notes"

$ProjMgmt = "0.Project Management"

$SW            = "0.Software"
$RVLicensing   = "0.Software\0.RoomView.License"
$RVNotes       = "0.Software\0.RoomView.Notes"
$SQLLicensing  = "0.Software\database.SQL.Licensing"
$SQLNotes      = "0.Software\database.SQL.Notes"
$FRVMarketing  = "0.Software\Fusion RV.Marketing"
$FRVNetworking = "0.Software\Fusion RV.Networking"
$FRVNotes      = "0.Software\Fusion RV.Notes"


###############################
#create the directory structure
###############################

md -Path $containerFolder -Name $rootFolder

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder
md "eControl and xPanels"
md "Fusion Server" #$subRoot1
md "Getting Started as a User"
md "Project Management"
md "RoomView Connected Displays"
md "Scheduling Enhancement and Panels" #$subRoot2
md "SQL Server" #$subRoot3

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder\$subRoot1
md "CEN-RVS"
md "Licenseing Information"
md "Networking"
md "Official Documentation"
md "Prerequisites, including powerShell script"
md "Product Info"
md "Requirements"
md "Tech Info"
md "Windows Authentication to Fusion RV"

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder\$subRoot2
md "Outlook Add-in"
md "Scheduling Panels" #$subRoot2sub1

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder\$subRoot2\$subRoot2sub1
md "TPMC-3SM"
md "TPMC-4SM"
md "TPMC-4SM-FD"
md "TSW-730"

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder\$subRoot3
md "Multi-database model only"
md "SQL Licensing"
```

Is there any benefits to creating the leafiest most subdirectories and by implication making PowerShell create the middle ones?

Are there any drawbacks to doing it this way?

Comment: The drawback is that this script is ridiculously long, complicated, and difficult to maintain. =) Please change your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wound up ending with:

```
# Compiles the Fusion packet for distribution

###############################
###########Variables###########
###############################

#folder structure
$FSG = "F:\FSG"
$containerFolder = "Packet.Fusion for IT and AV Professionals"
$rootFolder      = "Fusion for IT and AV pros $(Get-Date -format “MM-dd-yyyy”)"
$subRoot1        = "Fusion Server"
$subRoot2        = "Scheduling Enhancement and Panels"
$subRoot2sub1    = "Scheduling Panels"
$subRoot3        = "SQL Server"

#source folders
$HW      = "0.Hardware"
$3SMDoc  = "0.Hardware\TPMC-3SM.Documentation"
$4SMDoc  = "0.Hardware\TPMC-4SM.Documentation"
$4SMDDoc = "0.Hardware\TPMC-4SM-FD.Documentation"
$730Doc  = "0.Hardware\TSW-730.Documentation"
$730OLH  = "0.Hardware\TSW-730.OLH"
$CENRVS  = "0.Hardware\CEN-RVS.Notes"

$ProjMgmt = "0.Project Management"

$SW            = "0.Software"
$RVLicensing   = "0.Software\0.RoomView.License"
$RVNotes       = "0.Software\0.RoomView.Notes"
$SQLLicensing  = "0.Software\database.SQL.Licensing"
$SQLNotes      = "0.Software\database.SQL.Notes"
$FRVMarketing  = "0.Software\Fusion RV.Marketing"
$FRVNetworking = "0.Software\Fusion RV.Networking"
$FRVNotes      = "0.Software\Fusion RV.Notes"


###############################
#create the directory structure
###############################

md -Path $containerFolder -Name $rootFolder

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder
md "eControl and xPanels"
md "Fusion Server" #$subRoot1
md "Getting Started as a User"
md "Project Management"
md "RoomView Connected Displays"
md "Scheduling Enhancement and Panels" #$subRoot2
md "SQL Server" #$subRoot3

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder\$subRoot1
md "CEN-RVS"
md "Licenseing Information"
md "Networking"
md "Official Documentation"
md "Prerequisites, including powerShell script"
md "Product Info"
md "Requirements"
md "Tech Info"
md "Windows Authentication to Fusion RV"

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder\$subRoot2
md "Outlook Add-in"
md "Scheduling Panels" #$subRoot2sub1

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder\$subRoot2\$subRoot2sub1
md "TPMC-3SM"
md "TPMC-4SM"
md "TPMC-4SM-FD"
md "TSW-730"

cd $FSG\$containerFolder\$rootFolder\$subRoot3
md "Multi-database model only"
md "SQL Licensing"
```

Answer (score 50):

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\NewPath\NewSubPath\AnotherSubDir\WowThisIsReallyNested -Force
```

That will create the full path, including all of the subdirectories.

Comment: Applying that to the OP's script, that would be:                
`New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$containerFolder\$rootFolder\subdirname"`. A shorter version: `New-Item "$containerFolder\$rootFolder\subdirname" -Type Directory` (**-Path** is the first positional parameter, so the parameter name can be omitted if it's in the first position; **-Type** is an alias for **-ItemType**.)

Comment: All though not explicitly stated -Force does not seem to be required.

Comment: You're right, it's not needed. It is required if you want to create a file in a directory that doesn't yet exist, and I'd wrongly assumed it was needed for directories as well.