# Powershell create many folders from a path

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a Path `C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4`.

I want to split the path and create each of the folder like in the shown structure.

Has anyone any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Why not simply do `New-Item -Type Directory 'C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4' -Force`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a subdirectory/subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982765/create-a-subdirectory-subfolder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to split the path, you can create all the folders and sub-folders in one command:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4 -Force
```